# How to make join for few columns in same table in postgres?

Tags: postgresql

I have a table.
The table has several columns with user ids.
There is only one table with users.
[image]

If there was one column, then everything is clear, we do join user_id = users.id and then use users.name.
What if there are multiple columns? How can I do a join on each of the columns?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can join the same table using different aliases.

```
select adduser.name as adduser,
    edituser.name as edituser, 
    deluser.name as deluser
from table as t
join users as adduser
    on t.adduser_id = adduser.id
join users as edituser
    on t.edituser_id = edituser.id   
join users as deluser
    on t.deluser_id = deluser.id
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT ua.name as adduser,
       ue.name as edituser,
       ud.name as deleteuser
FROM Table t
JOIN Users ua on t.adduser_id = ua.id
JOIN Users ue on t.edituser_id = ue.id
JOIN Users ud on t.deleteuser_id = ud.id;
```